# button clipping when starting off screen and using TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, button

I have a button that the user can drag around. When the button is moved out of the view it seems to clip the image that is in the button's background. If I then animate the partially offscreen button using TranslateAnimation the clipped image moves through the animation.

How can I ensure the background gets fully redrawn as the image animates to another position?

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the parent xml node.